# How to insert template in html using angular?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, html

Scenario:-
I have html page rendering as angular template/view. Now there are big number of such template.

Now these templates has **div** in header part that is fixed through out the templates, now is there some-way that we can define one sub-template at one place and just insert that sub-template in all pages.

So that if there are any modification to be made, I will make in sub-template and that will be reflected in all the page.

> Its like  **UserControls or Partials** that we have in ASP.Net.

I am using AgularJS 
Agreed that there are ui-routing for nested hosting but currently I am not looking for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a seperate html file as **template** for header if it includes complex or considerable amount of elements. create a directive for this template and use it as an attribute/customTag or include it in your html using ***ng-include***.

```
app.directive('header',function(){      
    return {
        restrict: 'E', //'E': element /'A': attribute
        templateUrl : 'templates/header.html'
    }   
});
```

use as attribute

```
<div header></div> // as Attribute
<header></header> // as element
```

if your header involves lot of functioning on it then you can also create a separate controller *(which will act as a child controller)* and add the controller to the above tags. such as

```
<header ng-controller="headerController"></header>
```

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
<div ng-include="path/to/template"></div>
```

Comment: This answer is simplest, and most directly does exactly the thing asked for. The other answers are probably more suitable for a real application, because quite commonly over time it becomes desirable to add some behavior as well as just a reused template. But that is more than needs to be understood for the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a directive template. This is a very simple directive with only the template information.
Eg:

```
<top-header></top-header>

module.directive('topHeader', function() {
    return { 

        templateUrl: 'path', 

        // append 
        replace: true, 

        // attribute restriction 
        restrict: 'E'

    } 
});
```